# Block spefic URL

Tags: nginx, url, block

I'm trying to block such kind of URL

https://example.com/#id=826c99368cc93a894267703e0fc2ed46

Tried

```
 if ( $request_uri = https://example.com/#id=826c99368cc93a894267703e0fc2ed46) { return 444; }

 location ~* https://example.com/#id=826c99368cc93a894267703e0fc2ed46 { deny all;} 

 if ( $query_string = "826c99368cc93a894267703e0fc2ed46" ) { return 404; }
```

No one of this solution didn't help

Comment: Your server does not receive that URL. Anything from the `#` onwards is [the fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) and is used by the browser and not actually sent to the server.